# Oracle: trying to create a local temp_id var, so that I can return a primary kery

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have a table called ERS_REIMBURSEMENTS which has a sequence for a primary key auto increment. Every time I enter a 'null' value for rebs_id, it enters a new row with the next rebs_id number.

What I would like to do in my query, is to RETURN the rebs_id so that I can add it to my java object.

```
INSERT INTO ERS_REIMBURSEMENTS(rebs_id, user_id_author, user_id_resolver, rebs_type, rebs_status, rebs_amount, rebs_description, rebs_receipt, rebs_submitted, rebs_resolved)
VALUES (null, 1, null, 1, 1, '10', 'testing', null, '12-SEP-12 10:31:19', null)
RETURNING rebs_id into temp_id;
```

Once I get that temp_id back in my java DAO class, I was going to do the following:

```
reb.setRebsId(rebs_id);
System.out.println("in DAO, rebs_id: " + rebs_id);
```

I tried declaring the temp_id in multiple ways, for example:

```
DECLARE temp_id NUMBER;
```

or
    DECLARE
  temp_id NUMBER := 10;

I keep getting this error:

```
Error starting at line : 59 in command -
```

DECLARE
  temp_id NUMBER;
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 2, column 17:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

begin function pragma procedure subtype type 
    current cursor delete
   exists prior
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

How would I be able to do that?

Comment: Can you please share your complete pl/sql procedure ? It is possible that you are looking at different place.